# Find Maximum value of a distribution

Tags: r

Question: I have a function `X`, and want to find the value `y` that maximizes `X(y)`.

```
set.seed(8)
A <- seq (1:20)
B <- c(0,rbinom(18,1,0.5),1)

X <- function (y) {
 fx <- prod(1*B-pnorm(A-y)*(-1)^B)
 fx
}

X(10)
[1] 3.615998e-40
X(11)
[1] 5.624095e-53
```

I know I can loop through `X(0)` to `X(20)`, but it is very time consuming. Is there a smarter way to do want I need?

Comment: Does y only take integer values? Method depends on that. If y must be an integer, then brute force search may be your best option

Comment: Find out where the derivative is zero.

Comment: Unfortunately y can be any real value.

Comment: The derivative is hard to calculate for this function

Comment: The function as given does not produce the values for X(10), X(11) that you state. Have you written the function correctly? Also, for any random seed, the function seems to be montonic and asymptotically approaching zero as y increases. Monotonic functions do not have maxima or minima. If your function did have a maxima, you coud use `optimise` or `Optim`

Comment: Plot the function with: `plot((-500:500)/100,sapply((-500:500)/100,X),type = "l")` and you'll see it is either increasing or decreasing (if you comment the random seed). This is no mathematical proof, though.

Comment: If you want to search only from 0 to 20 with a fine subdivision, do: `all(diff(sapply(seq(0,20,length.out = 100000),X)) >= 0)` and you'll get `[1] TRUE`.  Here you are calculating discrete differences and all of them have the same sign.

Comment: you may be able to solve this using the Ryacas package (or in yacas itself of course).

Comment: did any of these comments, or my answer, provide any useful information?

Answer (score 0):

`optimize()` converges to the maximum value in the interval:

```
optimize(X,c(0,20),maximum=TRUE)
## $maximum
## [1] 19.99993
## 
## $objective
## [1] 0
```

Plotting the curve confirms this.

```
x <- seq(0,20,length=1000)
y <- sapply(x,X)
plot(x,y,type="l")
```

[image]